# Integrating an array over all elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking to integrate an image with large dimensions (~4000 x 4000 in pixels), whereby the image is an array of numerous values of the order of 1E-6 and 1E-7.

Upon using the `print sum(my_array)` task, I receive this:

> [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]

The array is fine, and there are lots of 0s on the fringe of the array, hence why we see them here, but I want the total integrated value over all pixels, is there a really simplified way of achieving this for a large array with very small values? Perhaps with numpy?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by **integrate**? I assume this is not in the mathematical sense but perhaps add the RGB channels together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use the python built-in sum which is (or uses) an iterator. And iterating over nested lists (and iterating over `np.ndarray`s is like iterating over nested lists) will not work the way you need (except the array is one-dimensional). If you want the sum of all the values try this

```
import numpy as np
# Just an example array, you need to define your array here
my_array = np.random.normal(0,1e-7,10000).reshape(100,100)
# np.sum instead of normal python sum. If you have NaNs try np.nansum
np.sum(my_array)
# 2.9210826829167365e-06
```

what `sum` does is iterating over the first axis (rows) and building the sum of the columns. That's why you got a `list` as return.

Also I would recommend that you look over some of the examples of the numpy documentation or some numpy tutorial. Numpy has lots of great functions and also needs them because they are much faster and especially tuned for numpy arrays. The python built-ins should be treated with care when applied on python extensions.